# Keep layout in ul list after intertitle

Tags: css, list

I work on a questionnaire (I have a fixed input mask) and then have the opportunity to align the format in a separate CSS file.

I face an issue with a **list** where the layout is based on the **structure of the ul headers**: When adding an **intertitle**, the structure of the buttons does not follow the layout/width of the ul titles anymore and hence is **inconsistent**.

Is there any solution to the problem, i.e. can I add any CSS commands in the list or a separate file that enable me to keep a **consistent structure of the buttons also below the intertitle**?

Please find attached a **link** to the list of the questionnaire for your reference:

http://ww2.unipark.de/uc/hollnder_Goethe_Universit__t_Fra/4568/ospe.php?SES=e82a8e8bd5f573f68972ae65c373fbed&syid=243842&sid=243843&act=start&preview_mode=1

*(Code: 80a4231323d632d5 if asked: "Bitte geben Sie Ihre gültigen Zugangsdaten ein")*

Any solution to my problem would be super helpful! Many thanks!

Best,
Christian

Comment: Maybe you could try to add a reduced version of your code on a fiddle? Bitteschön? :)

Comment: Hi Fausto, 
Many thanks for your comment. In fact I use an external provider (unipark) for designing the questionnaire which has a specific input mask for the page. I can adjust the shown page via an external CSS file then.
Please let me know if I can provide any further input.
Many thanks for your help!
Best, Christian